# For loop with string input python

Tags: python

```
inputString = input()

inputString += 'B'

for i in range( len(inputString) ) :
    if i == 'A' : 
        print('Alpha')
    else:
        print('Bravo')
```

I'm trying to get the code to print Alpha everytime an A is encountered and Bravo whenever B is seen in the string. However, I'm not sure why it's not picking up the As when it reads through the string and only ends up executing the Else condition. Any advice?

Comment: You're iterating a `range`, so `i` is a number, not a character from your string.

Comment: i is a number, thus never equal to 'A'

Comment: Whenever you use "range(len(something)) in a for loop, something is wrong. In this case just iterate over inputString. ```for char in inputString:```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for i in range....` the `i` is just a number (try it, in your for loop put a `print(i)` and you'll see numbers). So you need to use that number to get the index of the string to check the letter:

```
inputString += 'B'

for i in range( len(inputString) ) :
    if inputString[i] == 'A' : 
        print('Alpha')
    else:
        print('Bravo')
```

Alternatively, just go through the string without using i:

```
inputString += 'B'

for letter in inputString:
    if letter == 'A' : 
        print('Alpha')
    else:
        print('Bravo')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea why it wasnt comparing cant believe i was this dumb. Appreciate the answer kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
inp = "ABAAAB"
for c in inp:
    if c == "A":
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for i in range( len(inputString) ) :
    if inputString[i] == 'A' : 
        print('Alpha')
    else:
        print('Bravo')`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through a range which is giving you numbers. You need to loop through the characters int the string.

```
inputString = input()

for i in inputString:
    if i == 'A' : 
        print('Alpha')
    else:
        print('Bravo')
```

Also a dict would be easier than an if statement:

```
inputString = input()
switch = {'A': 'Alpha', 'B': 'Bravo'}

for i in inputString:
   print(switch.get(i, i))
```